# Function to replace NULL or Empty value in HIVE SQL

Tags: sql, hadoop, select, hive, sql-update

I have a table where two of the columns are "customer_name" and "customer_name_modified". Is there a function I can write in my query to fill in the "customer_name_modified" value with "customer_name" when "customer_name_modified" is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select
    customer_name,
    case when customer_name_modified is null or customer_name_modified = '' 
        then customer_name 
        else customer_name_modified 
    end customer_name_modified 
from mytable
```

If you are looking for an `update` statement:

```
update mytable
set customer_name_modified = customer_name
where customer_name_modified is null or customer_name_modified = ''
```